# Test for Diagonal in Cell, if yes, return "P"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get a formula to return a "P" in a cell if the reference cell has a Diagonal Up line.

```
=IF(C3)xlDiagonalUp,"P",""))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you need to write your own function. Add the following code in a new module:

```
Function DiagonalUp(CellRef As Range) As String
  If (CellRef.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous) Then
   DiagonalUp = "P"
  Else
    DiagonalUp = ""
  End If
End Function
```

Then you can just call it like any other function:
e.g =DiagonalUp(E1)

Comment: It worked. However, I now realize that I did not explain what I needed well at all. I am needing the function to automatically update the return (like "=Sum" would update every time a value was changed). So, when the Diagonal Up line is present in the reference cell the return cell would show "P" and when the reference cell is changed to NOT having a Diagonal Up line, the return cell will automatically update to "" (empty). Is this possible, or have I hit an Excel roadblock?

Comment: There is no trigger that I can find that triggers on format change. The best you can do to update all your functions is to press F9.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, W_O_L_F. They will get me closer to the needed solution.